# Laravel. Redirect intended to post method

Tags: php, laravel-5, redirect, middleware

I'm using laravel 5 and this is my problem. User fill in form X and if he isin't logged in, he gets redirected to fill in more fields form OR he gets possibility to log in. Everything works just fine, if user fill in additional fields, but if he login, laravel redirects user to form X with GET method instead of POST.

This is how my middleware redirect looks like:

```
return redirect()->guest('user/additional-fields');
```

This redirect appears on successfull log in:

```
return redirect()->intended();
```

So on redirect intended i get error 
     MethodNotAllowedHttpException. URL is correct which is defined as POST method. What am I missing here? Why does laravel redirects intended as GET method? How could I solve this problem? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
Route::post('/user/log-in-post', ['as' => 'user-log-in-post', 'uses' => 'UserController@postUserLogIn']);
```

This is my route, I hope this is one you need.

Comment: It's better to check if user is logged BEFORE letting him access to your page, instead of checking if he is logged when POSTing data. In fact, you do check if the user is logged/has rights to POST your data, but if he doesn't. You must raise an exception and redirect to the appropriate error page.

Comment: Idea behind that is to let user write post if he wants avoid registration and let him log in, if he decides to write current post with an existing account.

Comment: hm... OK, I understand. You might use the old() method of Input facade to when re-accessing your controller after you being redirected. Input::old()

Comment: But how do i redirect back to view not a post method?

Comment: please let me see your user route, you can solve this issue by using named route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a named route to solve this issue:

Lets make a named route like this:

For Get

```
Route::get('user/additional-fields',array(
    'uses' => 'UserController@getAdditionalFields',
    'as'   => 'user.getAdditionalFields'
));
```

For post

```
Route::post('user/additional-fields',array(
    'uses' => 'UserController@postAdditionalFields',
    'as'   => 'user.postAdditionalFields'
));
```

So we can now ensure Laravel uses the right route by doing this

`return redirect()->guest(route('user.getAdditionalFields'));`

Also note that its not possible to redirect a `POST` because Laravel expects form to be submitted. SO you can't do this:

`return redirect()->guest(route('user.postAdditionalFields'));`

except you use something like cURL or GuzzleHttp simulate a post request

Comment: Hmm, i underastand ideo behind this, but problem is that redirection to post method happens on successfull login. This is my redirection after loggin in: return redirect()->intended(); How do i define this redirect?

Comment: Ok maybe its possible dough. this is what redirect method looks like in Laravel. `function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)
 {
  if (is_null($to)) return app('redirect');

  return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
 }` lemme see if this can be done  via $headers

Comment: @Evaldus Butkus Please do you also with to send some form data along to `redirect()->guest('user/additional-fields');`

Comment: Yes i do. return redirect()->guest('user/review/information/' .$code); So as i udnerstand I need to get to that view where post method happened.

Comment: hmm. can you make the request flow clearer? I understand 1. You do this `return redirect()->guest('user/additional-fields');` 2. From user/additional-fields controller method you now `return redirect()->intended();` please where does `return redirect()->guest('user/review/information/' .$code);` fits into this flow?

Comment: I will try to make it all clear. First(1): return redirect()->guest('user/review/information/' .$code); From there user can fill in additional information OR log in. If he loggs in (2):  return redirect()->intended(); and than error happens, becouse application redirects me  into POST method. Original post method route: Route::post('/review/new-post', ['as' => 'review-new-post', 'uses' => 'ReviewController@postReviewNew']);

Comment: This should be simple then. Please let me see the code for you routes especially `user/review/information/`. Do you have a similar post route like this `user/review/information/{code?}` that might be conflicting with get? or  did you forget to include `{code}` parameter?

Comment: Part with  user/review/information/{code} works just perfectly. I will repeat all the process. I fill in form X fields, on buton submit create record (if not logged in) middleware catches user and redirects him(user/review/information/{code}) and suggests him to fill in additional fields OR log in with exiting accout. If user decides to log in he get redirected back (redirect()->intended();), back means into form X view but into POST method and than error appears.

Comment: that's wired. its suppose to redirected you back to a get route. example, `user/review/information/123456` which return a view containing the form. please just to confirm just before return  `redirect()->intended()` do dd(\Session::get('url.entended')); so as to see if the URL is correct

Comment: It's becouse middleware starts working on POST method, so redirect intended redirect also to POST method. But laravel sees my POST method as  GET

Comment: so issue is likely from your middleware? please also share the code for your middleware

Comment: Issue is that applicatiuon redirects inteded into POST route, becouse middleware catches him there.  Route::group(['middleware' => 'reviewAuth'], function() {
  Route::post('/review/new-post', ['as' => 'review-new-post', 'uses' => 'ReviewController@postReviewNew']);
 });
Route redirect()->intended() redirects user into /review/new-pos with error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78900/discussion-between-digitlimit-and-evaldas-butkus).

Answer (score 1):

You have to trick Laravel router by passing an "_method" the inputs.

The best way I found is by adding tricking and rewriting the Authenticate middleware

You have to rewrite the handle method to allow your redirection with your new input.

```
redirect()->guest('your/path')->with('_method', session('url.entended.method', 'GET'));
```

When you want to redirect to a route using another method than GET, simply do a `Session::flash('url.entended.method', 'YOUR_METHOD')`.

Tell me if it do the trick

Comment: return  redirect()->guest('oams/admission-finish')->withInput([
                'sid'=>$req->sid,'regId'=>$req->regId])
                ->with(['_method'=> session('url.entended.method', 'POST')]);

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple Approach for **Post method** **Route** form **Controller**.

The idea behind this is, every Route always calls the **Action** method of a **Controller**. so that in that case you can directly call that method in place of Redirect action performed.

check a code sample of **XYZController**

```
 $registration =  Registration::find($req->regId);
 $registration->update([ 'STEP_COMPLETED' => 5]);  // Step 5 completed.

 # Call Post Method Route 
   return $this->admissionFinish($req);
```

> Note that **$req**  should have all parameter  that required in next
>   action Method.

Answer (score 1):

change the below code in app\exceptions\handler.php

```
use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;

protected function unauthenticated($request,AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    //return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    return redirect()->guest('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signinnew'); // change this part to your login router
}
```

And in routes(i.e api.php):

```
Route::Any('signinnew',          [UserLogonController::class, 'signinNew']);
```

This will work in laravel 8x