# Redirect route to post method routes

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-5.1

i'm using laravel 5.1, in that how can i redirect to particular post method routes in routes.php file itself

(i.e)

```
Route::post('admin/attributevalue','AttributeController@add_attribute_values');
```

In that how can i redirect into above routes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463258/laravel-redirect-intended-to-post-method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463258/laravel-redirect-intended-to-post-method

Answer (score 0):

```
function postAdmin(){
    //
}

Route::get('admin/attributevalue', postAdmin()) {
    //
});
```

You can do it like that in route.php